# File not being completely written

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read a system file on the Nexus 5 and rewrite it to a second file with some modifications I will make. The problem is even without my modifications the file is not written completely. Il gets almost to the end and then stops writing always at the same place. Stops at line 450 and only writes `<path name` when it should write `<path name="voice-tty-full-headphones">` and continue for 30 more lines...

Strangely if I export to a textview everything is there so the problem is not when reading the file but when writing to the new one. I have attached a copy of the file i'm working with along with a copy of the file thats being generated. I really have no idea what to try from here.

```
//Output File
File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "/xxx/mixer_paths.xml");
outputFile.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

//Input File
File internalStorage = Environment.getRootDirectory();
File inputFile = new File(internalStorage,"/etc/mixer_paths.xml");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
String line;


while ((line = br.readLine()) != null )
{
    text.append(line+"\n");
}

    myOutWriter.append(text);
    textView.setText(text);
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7p1cgu7ziyzydh1/mixer_paths_original.xml
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zs03xt4k52vetek/mixer_paths_new.xml

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to close the writer? I've made this mistake myself. Always close your readers and writers when you are done with them. It frees up the resources and in the case of the writer, makes sure to finish writing!

Comment: WOW, that was it, stupid error, I was closing the reader but not the writer. Looks like it works fine now :) I will now try with the modifications I wanted to make. Thank you